# How to change the whole number in file to decimal value

Tags: awk

I need to edit the amount in a file which is delimited by "|", I need to change the whole number in to  decimal for field 1 and 4 alone, Could some one help me here

INput

```
1|A|b|1|5468|k|l|78789
3434|c|d|3434|045958|l|h|784889
12000|e|f|12000|6767474|klk|kjjhf|890898
200000|g|h|200000|5676474|jfjjf|teyt|67878
```

Output

```
1.00|A|b|1.00|5468|k|l|78789
34.34|c|d|34.34|045958|l|h|784889
120.00|e|f|120.00|6767474|klk|kjjhf|890898
2000.00|g|h|2000.00|5676474|jfjjf|teyt|67878
```

Comment: What have you tried already? What is the problem you are having with your current code?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Your question is also not clear? Which condition exists to decide if the number needs to be divided by 100?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"|" '
{
  if(/0+$/){
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
       $i=substr($i,1,length($i)-1)"."substr($i,length($i)-1)
     }
  }
  else{
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
       $i=sprintf("%.02f",$i)
     }
  }
}
1
' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1.00|1.00
3434.00|3434.00
1200.00|1200.00
20000.00|20000.00
```

Comment: @SGS, please do let me know reason for removing this answer as correct answer??